# Is there a way I can share a printer on a multi user computer so it is available even if no one is logged in?

Tags: printing

I have a USB printer attached to a desktop that several in the family would like to access from their laptops.  You never know who will be logged in on the desktop or if in fact anyone is.  Every computer is running either stock 14.04 or 14.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a detailed step-by-step guide on how to set up shared printers with Ubuntu over here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

Comment: There shouldn't be the need for anyone to be logged into the desktop the printer is attached to. The printing system is started on boot.